# FFmpeg no such filter 'tpad'

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a simple gif. I am not in general familiar with FFmpeg commands so I assume it's just my syntax being wrong, but what I'm using is straight from an answer here so I thought it would work.

I'm trying to add a delay on the last frame of my gif.

```
ffmpeg -i out.gif -vf tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=2 out2.gif
```

But I'm getting this when I try it:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.11-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened -                                                                                      -libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enabl                                                                                      e-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls                                                                                       --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-lib                                                                                      caca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreet                                                                                      ype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --en                                                                                      able-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enabl                                                                                      e-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-li                                                                                      bsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --                                                                                      enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enabl                                                                                      e-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --e                                                                                      nable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enabl                                                                                      e-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-f                                                                                      rei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, gif, from 'out.gif':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: gif, bgra, 780x530, 6 fps, 15 tbr, 100 tbn, 100 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (gif (native) -> gif (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x5609c471d520] No such filter: 'tpad'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Too old of a version (2 major version behind the current). `tpad` was introduced in v4.2. Grab the latest release/nightly

Comment: How strange. I just installed it! I just assumed it was a new version.

Comment: IIRC, ubuntu's package manager locks package versions to the os release. see [the listing](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg). Grab the static build from [John van Sickle's website](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and follow his instruction on the FAQ page.